# How can I count down from the server time to the nearest half-hour in Microtime in JS/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, time, easeljs, createjs

I currently have a partial solution working, but for the life of me I can't figure out the correct iteration. I could also be doing this completely wrong. First in PHP, I get the current time and convert it to microseconds. It's calculated so the difference is given to the nearest half-hour:

```
$remaining = 30 - (date('i', time()) % 30);
```

That is placed into a JSON file and sent to the system I'm writing in Javascript, with EaselJS.
(EDIT: I forgot to mention it's converted into MicroTime just before being sent)

Once the file is loaded, a bool is flipped to "true" and it starts counting down:

```
function UpdateGame(event)
{
    if (ready == true)
    {
        stage.update();

        if (TickTimerReady == true)
        {
            ticktimer = ticktimer - 1000000;
            console.log(ticktimer);
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the tricky part: UpdateGame is a tick-based event, running at 40 FPS. How can I calculate the proper values to subtract from ticktimer so that it hits the half-hour at the same time the server does? I understand it may be slightly off... but 1000000 is clearly not it!

Comment: it would be simpler to just calc the offset between server and client, and do all the math on the client. something like (new Date(document.lastModified) - performance.timing.domainLookupEnd) should calc the offset

Comment: I don't recognize performance.timing. How can that be used?

Comment: new Date( performance.timing.responseEnd) is very close to the moment your server will return its date, but according to the client's clock. by subtracting the server time from the client time, you arrive at the offset. from there, the client need simply add/subtract the offset with any date to convert to server time. the performance.timing values are nice because they don't require lag compensation, so you can sync within 15-25 ms reliably. the OS can adjust the clock without notice however, so it's wise to periodically recalc the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following where you could call `timer()` when the server responds and just do whatever you need to do once it's  been 30 minutes.

```
var seconds = 0;
timer = function(){ setInterval(count,1000); }
count = function(){ 
    seconds++; 
    if (seconds === (30*60)) window.alert("it's been 30 minutes do stuff");
}
```